# SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, html, web

I am trying to do some web scraping of movie reviews from IMDB through the following code:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
url='https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'
response= requests.get(url)
```

and am getting this error :

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.imdb.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /title/tt0068646/reviews?ref_=tt_urv (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because certification validation has failed (which is odd given that you are opening IMDB). You can turn off certification validation by setting the `verify` parameter to false:

```
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

As for why certificate validation is failing, I guess, it's because the date and time on your machine are not correctly set.

Comment: I did this, but I get the error: ```name 'url' is not defined``` - Any thoughts? I'm VERY new.

Comment: You're getting `name 'url' is not defined` because you have not initialized the variable `url` in your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can try restarting the network or computer。This may work。

Comment: Users are presumed to have tried obvious troubleshooting strategies before posting their question.

Comment: Not everyone restarts their computer before searching for problems。I encountered this issue because I turned on VPN and turning it off did not work, so I restarted the computer.